# ASP.Net Email settings problems

Tags: asp.net

I have a website that has a form customers fill in. At the end, when they send it, admin gets an email with cutomers fields, but i want that email to be sent to the customer as well. I have this in my Web.config:

```
</mailSettings>
</system.net>
<appSettings>
<add key="emailTo" value="info@info.com"/>
```

How can i make it send it to customers as well?

Thanks

Comment: Where is your code that sends the email. Can you please attach it so that we can help you?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version for sending mail we've used before:

```
string SMTP_SEVER = "smtpserver";
System.Net.Mail.MailMessage oMail = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
System.Net.Mail.MailAddress oAddress = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("email@email.com");
oMail.From = oAddress;
oMail.Subject = "subject line of email";
oMail.Body = "body of email";
//use this if you want to format the line above with html
oMail.IsBodyHtml = true;
oMail.To.Add("send to");
System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient oSMTP = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient(SMTP_SEVER);
oSMTP.Send(oMail);
```

how we're using this is we have a form that people fill out and in the controller we grab the user's email from the form and put it in the oMail.To.Add() part above.  The oAddress (line 3 above) can also be stored in the config if you want or anywhere else (it's the admin email, or whoever you want the email to appear to be coming from"

Answer (score 0):

The customer's email is variable, right? You don't want to use a config setting in this case unless this page is for one customer.

You need to give the customer a text field to type in an email address or get it from a database.